# What is the right format for mappings to be passed when creating an index?

Tags: python, elasticsearch

I am trying to create a new index (elasticsearch `2.0.0-beta2`) together with mappings.

I am passing (either to `pyelasticsearch` or `elasticsearch.client`) the following mapping (this is a `json.dumps` of the dict):

```
{
  "mappings": {
    "vulnerability": {
      "_timestamp": {
        "enabled": true,
        "path": "HOST_START_iso"
      },
      "properties": {
        "scan_name": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "severity": {
          "type": "string",
          "index": "not_analyzed"
        },
        "HOST_START_iso": {
          "format": "epoch_millis||dateOptionalTime",
          "type": "date"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The creation of the index fails with a `TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception')` (below is the traceback for `elasticsearch.client`, the mapping above is in `mapping`)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/dev/Scans/L_build_vulns_index.py", line 38, in <module>
    elasticsearch.client.IndicesClient(client=es).create(index=vulns_index, body=mapping)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\utils.py", line 69, in _wrapped
    return func(*args, params=params, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\client\indices.py", line 102, in create
    params=params, body=body)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\transport.py", line 307, in perform_request
    status, headers, data = connection.perform_request(method, url, params, body, ignore=ignore, timeout=timeout)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\http_urllib3.py", line 89, in perform_request
    self._raise_error(response.status, raw_data)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\site-packages\elasticsearch\connection\base.py", line 105, in _raise_error
    raise HTTP_EXCEPTIONS.get(status_code, TransportError)(status_code, error_message, additional_info)
elasticsearch.exceptions.RequestError: TransportError(400, 'mapper_parsing_exception')
```

I get this mapping from another index and I do not understand what is wrong with the the structure (I also tried to remove the outermost `mappings`, the result is that the index is created, but without any mapping).

Note: this script used to work in the past, the only memorable change I can think of is an upgrade of elasticsearch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that in 2.0 the `_timestamp` field [has been deprecated](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_mapping_changes.html#_literal__timestamp_literal_and_literal__ttl_literal_deprecated).

The main issue, though, is that the `path` property is [no longer available](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/_mapping_changes.html#migration-meta-fields) (+ [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/2.0/mapping-timestamp-field.html)).

Comment: Thanks, so if I understand correctly, instead of `path` there should now be a field `timestamp` in `_source` which will be automagically recognized as the timestamp is `_timestamp`is enabled in the mappings?

Comment: As of 2.0 you should not use `_timestamp` at all anymore, but have a date field in your source that you use as timestamp, instead.

Comment: OK, I did not realized, reading the docs you linked to, that `_timestamp` is **completely** deprecated (and not merely cut down in functionality). I will just drop that par from the mappings and see if it fixes the problem.